# In Cocoa, what is the correct way to get binary data from a local file that is not in the app bundle?

Tags: swift, cocoa

My application requires audio data on the local disk that is not in the app bundle. All solutions I have seen to this involve using an instance of a URLSession dataTask, however all these solutions are focused on streaming data from a remote server as opposed to getting data from the local disk. All documentation about URLSession seems to be about getting data from a remote server also.

So my question is simply - is URLSession actually the correct way to get binary from disk as opposed to over a network?

Comment: It's not that simple. It depends on whether the app is sandboxed or not. And no, `URLSession` is not the correct way.

Comment: Where in the local disk is the file that you want to use, do you have a URL pointing to it?

Comment: @EmilioPelaez ok so now I have this working if the user selects a file using a modal window (NSOpenPanel)... file could be in any directory. If I hard code a url path in the souce code to test it doesn't work though

Comment: @EmilioPelaez .... i.e. passing the path into 'let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)' ...returns an error saying there is no such file... not sure why

Comment: @chemFour then you need to check if the url is valid; in case it is, though if it does point to a file you have permissions to read from. This is why I've answered before to check `FileManager` documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Check `FileManager`, and if you are trying to get a data streaming `InputStream`.